# How to login to a website using requests.post python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/login
.
This is the website where i want to send login details and log myself in to extract other features. Can somebody help me do that using (Post) method of requests. 
I dont want to use selenium
This is what i have tried

```
LOGIN = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/login'
PROTECTED_PAGE = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/home'
payload = {
'username': 'username',
'password': 'pwd'
}
import requests

s = requests.session()

response = s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
print(response.text)
stuff = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)
print(stuff.text)
```

and this is what i am getting in return

> Not Acceptable!
>
> ## Not Acceptable!
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Comment: Have you read the requests documentation and/or worked through a tutorial?  What is your specific question?

Comment: I just want to login to that website using (post) method, i have tried a lot but it ain't working.

Comment: _i have tried a lot but it ain't working_ Show us.

Comment: LOGIN = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/login'

PROTECTED_PAGE = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/home'

payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'pwd'
}

import requests

s = requests.session()

response = s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)

print(response.text)

stuff = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)

print(stuff.text)

Comment: This is what i am getting in return
<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments.  Please edit the question and put the code there.

Comment: hi, i have edited the question, can you please have a look and tell me some solution if you have

Comment: Try doing a `GET` on the login page first.  This gives the server a chance to set cookies.

Comment: I have tried it as well, it is giving me same output. Not Acceptable

Answer (score 3):

This website use `nonce` for security purpose in login request. You can find `nonce` on loin page and send `nonce` into `payload` with username and password. Add `headers` in your request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/login'
protected_page_url = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/home'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
}

# Create Session.
s = requests.session()

# Get nonce from Login page.
response = s.get(login_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
nonce = soup.find('input', {'id': 'woocommerce-login-nonce'}).get('value')

# Add Host, Origin and Referer into headers.
headers['Host'] = 'order.uniteduk.co.uk'
headers['Origin'] = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk'
headers['Referer'] = 'http://order.uniteduk.co.uk/index.php/login'

# Add nonce in payload.
payload = {
    "username":"YourUsername",
    "password":"YourPassword",
    "woocommerce-login-nonce":nonce,
    "_wp_http_referer":"/furniture/my-account/",
    "login":"Login"}

# Login Request.
response = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

# Login Protected Page Request.
stuff = s.get(protected_page_url, headers=headers)
print(stuff.text)
```